# Unable to access additional data with token in Web api 2 authentication

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, owin, bearer-token

I am using Web Api 2 and implemented custom token based authentication. It is working fine but I want to get few extra properties values in response. Even though I have added new claims and also added new properties to get their values in response but I am still get only three values in response which are 'access_token', "token_type" and "expires_in". How can I get more values in response.
**This is my code:**

```
  public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        if(context.UserName == "user" && context.Password=="user")
        {
             var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrators"));

            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("MyClaim", "I don't know"));

            var props = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {  "name", "John" },
                { "surname", "Smith" },
                { "age", "40" },
                { "gender", "Male" }
            });

            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
            context.Validated(ticket);
        }
        else
        {
            context.SetError("Invalid_Grant", "Provided username and password is incorrect");
            return;
        }
    }
```

**This is the output I am getting**

```
{
```

"access_token": "xxxxx",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 86399
}

Comment: which class contains this method **GrantResourceOwnerCredentials**

Comment: @Aravind public class AuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider{-----}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the additional claims and properties are not supposed to appear as additional fields in the response, but are encoded in the access_token itself.
If you're using JWT (JSON Web Tokens) you can view the contents of the generated token at https://jwt.io/ 
Just paste your token into the left window and see the decoded token including all your claims on the right side.

Comment: Yes you are right, these appears in the token itself.